# Document names and proper nouns/definite articles

Tags: definite-articles

I'm a translator and not a native speaker of English and have some troubles understanding definite articles.

Any feedback for my problem would be of great help for me.

What is the rule for document names and proper nouns? I need to translate the following sentence into English: "Documents that increase **Inventory and stock list amount** are as follows..." Now, 'Inventory and stock list' is a proper noun in this case, it is a caption in our software, but in this context I refer to **amount**, why I don't need the definite article there? What will modify that noun? Would it be incorrect to say: "Documents that increase **the** Inventory and stock list amount are as follows..."

I need a grammatical explanation for this.
'It sounds good but I don't know why' rule is driving me crazy.

Comment: The _Inventory and stock list amount_ can be increased by the following documents: ... - would be my preference, with or without the `The` since I would scan for the title and not for the word `documents`

Comment: Thanks! But why? 'The' refers to amount? Hm.. Ok. :) Still confused, but thanks anyway!

Comment: As your example is rather technical, I'm not sure what 'Inventory and stock list amount' means exactly. However, '_Inventory and stock list_' is being used as a **compound modifier** of amount, like '_association football_ results' or '_duck-egg-blue_ dress'. Modifiers of nouns do not remove the requirement for a relevant article: the association football results; a duck-egg-blue dress. See Trevor's answer for where to use the dfinite article.

Answer (score 2):

While I wouldn't dare to say that this is a 'rule', I would say that the definite article *the* is generally used before mass / uncountable nouns when you are referring to a **specific instance** of that noun.

In your example, you are referring to *the **Inventory and stock list** amount*, rather than, say, *the **purchase** amount*, or *the **sales** amount*, or *the amount **of your salary***.

Similarly, you might say:

> *The **twenty people** on the course* - as distinct from *people in general* (no article), or the millions of people not on the course.
>   *The **hospital** staff* - as distinct from *The **university** staff*
>   *The **river** water* - as distinct from *water in general* (no article), or from *The **lake** water*.

Comment: Thanks so much. So the first comment says I can 'use or omit' the definite article and your comment says I can use 'the'. What is the grammatical rule? Thanks so much for taking the tome to answer, I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't give you a 'rule' - amongst other reasons, English does not have official 'rules'! But I would say that (1) I disagree with @mplungjan that *the* may be omitted; (2) I'm not saying you **can** use *the*, I'm saying you **should** use *the*; and (3) Edwin's comment suggests that he also thinks *the* or *a* **should** be included.